# Sit div inside another div?

Tags: css, html, position, stylesheet

I want my 'header' div to sit within the 'container' div. At the moment the 'header' div is sitting above the 'container' div and I cannot seem to put it in it. Below is the coding. Thanks for the help.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#body {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 956px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F00;
    border-width: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

Comment: by looking at the code you posted, the header is inside of the container. Add some text above and under the header and you will see http://jsfiddle.net/fVRnX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inside it. Remove the background color on your header and you'll see the container's background behind.

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the container, just the looks like it's on top because of the colors. Open up w/e browser tools you prefer and take a look at the container div.

Answer (score 0):

It is inside your container. Adding padding or remove the background will make it more visable

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWgsg/)

```
#body {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:20px;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 956px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F00;
    border-width: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set background color to transparent or just remove it temporarily, you'll see that the header is inside there